# Embedly Not Using Featured Images

Tags: wordpress, image, embedly

I am creating a blog post featuring our top 25 posts and on some of them, Embedly displays the posts' featured image but on a few of them, it only pulls the website header.  Any ways to edit the content that is being shown? TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set the image using the `data-card-image` property in the html: http://embed.ly/docs/products/cards#customize

Comment: can you give an example of the card customizations, pretty hard to find one

Comment: can data-card-image also be used to force embedly to not take any image as preview? like data-card-image: none